# Refresh does not refresh

Tags: c#

I made an user control and I draw a rectangle directly in the window, like this (this is a simplified version):

```
private int rec_len = 200;
private void Draw_()
{
    Pen pn = new Pen( Color.Black, WIDTH_LINE );
    Graphics graph = this.CreateGraphics();
    graph.Clear( Color.Transparent );
    this.Refresh();
    graph.DrawRectangle( pn, 20, 10, rec_len, 40 );
    this.Refresh();
    graph.Dispose();
}
public void button_Build_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{ rec_len += 10;  Draw_(); }
```

The strange thing is that the second refresh actually poses a problem: if I comment it out, the rectangle is visible, if I let it in the code, the rectangle is not visible. In the real code I have to draw more than a rectangle and I want the refresh at the end, otherwise the background is visible between the moment I erase old drawing and the moment the new one is ready.

Comment: what's the problem ?? do you want the rectangle ?

Comment: Yes, I want the rectangle to be visible.

Comment: Why do you need the second refresh then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is not a real problem. The question is unlikely to be helpful for future readers.

Comment: @Tim Because otherwise, for a short period of time, I will have no drawing: old one is erased and the new one is not yet shown. And this gap is noticeable. I want the new drawing to be shown immediately after the previous one is erased.

Comment: try using two alternating overlapping graphs. generate graph 2 on hidden one and then hide the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surface of a control is not stored: When you paint on a control, the drawing is not saved and need to be redrawn each time the control is repainted (After a refresh for example). To create a persistante graphic, you can create a bitmap, draw on the bitmap and assign this bitmap to the BackgroundImage property.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
void Initialize() 
{
    this.BackgroundImage = bmp;
}

private int rec_len = 200;
private void Draw_() 
{
    Pen pn = new Pen(Color.Black, WIDTH_LINE);
    using (Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        graph.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        this.Refresh();
        graph.DrawRectangle(pn, 20, 10, rec_len, 40);
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
public void button_Build_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { rec_len += 10; Draw_(); }
```